# Rectangle with negative height or width don't use contain method properly?

Tags: c#, xna

So I'm trying to find whether a point is contained within a rectangle. It works fine when both the height and width of the rectangle are positive or negative but not only one is negative. The whole idea of a rectangle having a negative width or height is kind off odd but it seemed to deal with it fine when they were both negative. So I was wondering how XNA deals with the contains method in this scenario? shouldn't it just not accept it in this case if it doesn't work.

I'm using it to create an rts style selection box just to define that rectangle so I can tell what's inside it. Here's my code:

```
if (InputHandler.IsLeftMouseHeld() == true)
{
    selectionBoxRectangle = new Rectangle(selectionBoxRectangle.X,
      selectionBoxRectangle.Y,
      (int)Vector2.Transform(InputHandler.MousePosition(),
      Matrix.Invert(camera.Transformation)).X - selectionBoxRectangle.X,
      (int)Vector2.Transform(InputHandler.MousePosition(),
      Matrix.Invert(camera.Transformation)).Y - selectionBoxRectangle.Y);

    foreach(ControllableCharacter character in characters.OfType<ControllableCharacter>())
    {
        if (selectionBoxRectangle.Contains(character.DestRectangle.Center) == true
          || character.DestRectangle.Contains(selectionBoxRectangle))
        {
            character.Selected = true;
            character.Color = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            character.Selected = false;
            character.Color = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to deal with it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you decompile the XNA code for Rectangle, you can see the implementation here:

```
public bool Contains(Point value)
{
    return this.X <= value.X && value.X < this.X + this.Width && this.Y <= value.Y && value.Y < this.Y + this.Height;
}
```

Comment: Okay. But I still don't understand how it works when both height and width are negative?

Answer (score 1):

Here's extension method that can help if you lazy as I am

```
public static bool ContainsExt(this RectangleF rect, PointF point)
{
    bool widthOk;
    bool heightOk;

    if (rect.Width < 0)
    {
        widthOk = rect.X >= point.X && point.X > rect.X + rect.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        widthOk = rect.X <= point.X && point.X < rect.X + rect.Width;
    }

    if (rect.Height < 0)
    {
        heightOk = rect.Y >= point.Y && point.Y > rect.Y + rect.Height;
    }
    else
    {
        heightOk = rect.Y <= point.Y && point.Y < rect.Y + rect.Height;
    }

    return widthOk && heightOk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own method that will work with special cases better than default methods.

Like so:

```
bool RectangleContainsPoint(Rectangle rect, Point p)
{
    if (rect.Width < 0 && rect.Height >=0 ||
        rect.Width >=0 && rect.Height < 0)  // if in this case you have problems

        return MyImplementationOfContains(rect, p);
    else
        return Rectangle.Contains(rect, p);
}

bool MyImplementationOfContains(Rectangle rect, Point p)
{
    // as the name of this method suggests, your implementation
}
```

Comment: Yeah good idea, I actually had to have two implementations, one when width is negative and height is positive and one for when the opposite is true.